# OpenSSL issue with Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, bundle, rbenv

I am working on a project with has ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.15. Struggling to bundle.

I installed ruby with **rbenv (1.1.1)**

ruby -v returns

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [i686-darwin18.2.0]
```

rails -v returns

```
rbenv: rails: command not found
The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
2.3.3
2.3.4
```

bundle install returns

```
Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in 
your Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.
```

Dying to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed? What package manager do you use? With Homebrew a simple `brew install openssl` might solve the issue.

Comment: Just tried with brew but didn't work. Same error "Could not load OpenSSL..."

Comment: You say that you installed OpenSSL via Homebrew, _re-installed_ Ruby (both without error message) and then `bundle install` still shows the exact same error message?

Comment: ok got the solution. Downgraded the bundle to 1.10.6 and ran this line

"CONFIGURE_OPTS=“--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl” rbenv install 1.8.7-p370"